# love letter passes for base test cases

Tags: java, string, replace, palindrome

Loveletter code question: James found a love letter his friend Harry has written for his girlfriend. James is a prankster, so he decides to meddle with the letter. He changes all the words in the letter into palindromes.

To do this, he follows 2 rules:

(a) He can reduce the value of a letter, e.g. he can change 'd' to 'c', but he cannot change 'c' to 'd'. 
(b) In order to form a palindrome, if he has to repeatedly reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes 'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be changed.

Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a given string into a palindrome.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static int getAscii(char letter)
    {
        return (int)letter;
    }

    static boolean checkPalindrome(String str, int strLen)
    {
        String revStr ="";
        for(int i=strLen;i >= 0;i--)
        {
            revStr = revStr + str.charAt(i);
        }

        if(str.equals(revStr))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void reduceAscii(String str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        str = str.toString();
        int strLen = str.length()-1;
        int numOfOperations=0;
        char letter;

        for(int j=strLen; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            letter = str.charAt(j);
            while(getAscii(letter) > 97 && getAscii(letter) <= 122)
               {
                   if(checkPalindrome(str, strLen))
                   {
                       break;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       int asciiValofLetter = (char)getAscii(letter);
                       char charToreplace = (char)(asciiValofLetter-1);
                       sb.setCharAt(j, charToreplace);
                       str = sb.toString();
                       letter = charToreplace;
                       numOfOperations++;
                   }
               }
        }
        System.out.println(numOfOperations);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfTestCases;
        String str;
        numOfTestCases = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i < numOfTestCases; i++)
        {
            str = sc.next();
            Solution.reduceAscii(str);
        }
    }
}
```

My code passes for abc, abcd, abcba but fails for lot of test cases. Here are some:

```
pue
heubsbn
feazhaxpux
hmhcy
tmp
```

Comment: Are you saying your code passes when the input is already a palindrome but fails in all other cases? Have you tried stepping through it in an IDE debugger? That's the place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks overly complicated. You're asked to find the number of operations required, not the actual result.

Java's not my thing, so here's some pseudocode:

```
Number of letters to change = int(length of string/2) (for a seven letter string we change three letters)
Total operations = 0

for n=0 to number of letters to change
    take nth letter and (string length-n)th letter

    (number of operations on each letter is difference of ASCII values so...)
    subtract ASCII value of first letter from ASCII value of second
    add absolute value of this to your total

next letter

print total.
```

Comment: Well thanks for giving me alternative solution but my main problem is to fix my solution with those mentioned test cases and not to give me a new solution/pseudo code. Once I know what I was doing wrong then i can go with other better solutions

Comment: The solution as provided in the OP doesn't work because it only considers 1 character at a time starting at the end of the string. The take away here is that you *must* consider both "halves" of the string in the character reduction portion of the algorithm. That part isn't an alternative its a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


public class ConvertToPal {

    public ConvertToPal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter a string to be palindromized! ");
        String str = br.readLine();
        char[] strArr = str.toCharArray();
        int size = strArr.length;
        int numOfOperations = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (size/2) ; i++){
            int dif = (getAscii(strArr[i])-getAscii(strArr[size-1-i]));
            if (dif > 0){
                strArr[i] = strArr[size-1-i];
                numOfOperations += Math.abs(dif);
            }
            if(dif < 0){
                strArr[size-1-i] = strArr[i];
                numOfOperations += Math.abs(dif);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new String(strArr));
        System.out.println("num of ops: "+ numOfOperations);
    }
    static int getAscii(char letter){
        return (int)letter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how this code help's the OP solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method in Java to achieve this

```
public int palindromeCount(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        int front = (int) s.charAt(i);
        int back = (int) s.charAt(j);
        count += (Math.abs(front - back));
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return count;
}
```